# Wordpress Browser Cache with W3-Total-Cache doesn't show new posts

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm running the latest version of both Wordpress (3.5.1) and the always popular W3 Total Cache (0.9.2.8), but I'm having issues with the browser cache. Basically I can't figure out the settings to make it so that my homepage isn't being cached.

Whenever I turn on the browser cache, it effectively caches my homepage and stops showing any new posts that I make. My inclination is to lower the HTML & XML Expires header lifetime down to something like 900 seconds (15 minutes), but I'm not 100% sure that would solve my problem here.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: How often are you pushing new content? Remember, the majority of most sites' traffic is the front page, so if you don't cache that you're losing the benefit of caching in the first place. Lowering the cache duration to something small should alleviate the problem. It means people will wait no longer than X minutes to see new posts on the home page.

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps necessary to make sure that the browsers fetch the updated HTML pages (ex: home page).

## Step 1

Uncheck 'Set expires header' at your site's  `wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_browsercache#html_xml`, for 'HTML & XML' files.

Whenever a browser sees an `Expires` header, it (the browser) will fetch the next version of that particular HTML page only after it expires. The `Expires` header specifies a date after which a resource (home page / HTML page) is invalid.

## Step 2

In your site's 'Browser Cache' at `wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_browsercache#html_xml`, for 'HTML & XML' files, the 'Cache Control Policy' should probably be 'cache with max-age and validation ("max-age=EXPIRES_SECONDS, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate").

Like the 'expires' header, the `max-age` header specifies how long a resource (home page / HTML page) is valid after it is downloaded.

When using this cache control policy, W3 Total Cache would additionally send two headers...

1. `Last-Modified` header
2. `ETag` header

The use of `ETag` is redundant (IMO), when `Last-Modified` header is present. So, it is safe to remove `ETag` header after it is generated by W3 Total Cache.

When the home page is not updated and when browsers tries to fetch the same page that is already in the browser cache, the W3 Total Cache sends `304 Not Modified` status code. If the home page is updated and if the browsers tries to fetch the same page that is already in the browser cache, W3 Total Cache sends the updated home page with the updated `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers.

For more details on `Expires` and `max-age` headers, please check out... https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching

If you use Firefox, you may use [Live HTTP Headers add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to check how all the above headers work in real time.

Comment: I followed these steps but it didn't work out. The front page still shows old posts. I added a query string to the URL to test, and it showed all new posts. This means that it is the browser cache that is forcing the browser to show old posts. The browser is using cache even when I follow above steps. The expires time is equal to the date time. Thus it uses cache. Could anyone help?